# Mapping servlet url-pattern problem with eclipse

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

I am using Eclipse Java-EE and I'm trying to make a servlet from there. However, I see a problem with mapping url-pattern in web.xml, the tomcat server wont initialise when the value inside the url-mapping is not the same as the project name? Is there a way I can assign different url-mapping value apart for the project name? Thanks.

Comment: pls, give an example of your web.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for example your servlet definition is as below

```
 <!-- Define the servlet -->
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>yourServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.YourServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>yourServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Say, your application root context is "webapplication" and your server is running on localhost,port 8080. then you can access above servlet 
    http://localhost:8080/webapplication/servlet

if you are asking about Web Context root (webapplication in above example) then you can also change it. in eclipse, right click your project->`properties ->` Web Project Setting and change name of your appplication in Context Root field.